# Get current page name from url using laravel blade

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I want to get current page name from url using laravel blade, as I want to use it for dynamic manipulation and put it inside hidden value.

If the URL is `admin/coding/colors`, I want to get only `colors` page name.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want this param CairoCoder? Cant you handle this in the controller or repository?

Comment: @Bas I can do, but I am asking if there's a shortcut to do that directly with blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, try this:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

{{Request::segment(3)}}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to respond to any uri, irrespective of how many segments are in the url, try:

```
{{substr(strrchr(url()->current(),"/"),1)}}
```

This will always get the last segment of the request

Comment: Method getPath does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
{str_after(url()->current(), 'http://admin/coding/')}}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, how are you? Remember to always explain your code, dont just write the code "and done". Explain what you are using, why and how it works. Welcome to the StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain the value in the controller and give it as a variable to your view.
You can do that with the `segments` method of the Request.

```
$request->segments()[count($request->segments()) -1]
```

Your controller should look something like this:

```
public function someFunctionName(Request $request)
{
    $last_url_segment = $request->segments()[count($request->segments()) -1];
    return view('view.name', ['last_url_segment', $last_url_segment]);
}
```

Then, in your view, you can use the variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ $last_url_segment }}">
```